# Is Dart smart enough to automatically dispose variables?

Tags: dart

Is Dart smart enough to automatically dispose variables? for instance in the following code

```dart
class Foo {
 final streamController = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
 final textController = TextEditingController();
}
```

Must I manually call `textController.dispose()` and `streamController.close()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dart is a garbage collected language. If an object cannot be accessed by any code any more, if it makes not difference to the program whether it exists or not, the value might eventually be garbage collected. That will necessarily be completely invisible to the program, it's just a *memory optimization* to not keep things around which makes no difference.

Whether an object is actually unreachable/garbage-collectible depends on whether the program *or* the run-time system keeps a reachable reference to it, directly or indirectly.
Some objects are kept alive by the run-time system. For example, an open file needs to be remembered so that the system can close it and release the resource when the program ends, whether your code remembers it or not. In general, an allocated system resource should always be assumed to be alive in some way, and you need to dispose/close/cancel it to be sure it's released.

Dart does *not* try to guess whether one variable of an object is unreachable when the object itself is reachable. In the given example, if a `Foo` object instance is reachable, then so is the values of its variables. (If there is literally no references to `foo.streamController` anywhere in the program, including through `dynamic` invocations, that variable might be optimized away by the compiler, but I wouldn't depend on it).

If there is no reference to a `Foo` object, then whether the values of the variables are garbage collected depends on whether there are other references to them. I'll assume you're not keeping them around yourself, so the question is whether they are remembered by the run-time system.

I can't speak for `TextEditingController`. I'm guessing it's a Flutter thing. I do not know whether it contains any system resources.

The stream controller is only kept alive as long as its stream or that stream's listeners.
If there are no current listeners on the controller, and no-one has stored `foo.streamController.stream` anywhere, there won't be any references to the controller.
Even if there are listeners, `StreamSubscription`s, then if those subscriptions are not reachable, then the controller also isnt'.
(The one exception may be while a new event has recently been added to the controller, and a system timer has been set to deliver the event shortly later, but that's only for a very short while).